# Getting RoleCollection as a string

Tags: sharepoint, spuser

We can get the roles of an SPUser by `SPUser.Roles`.  But it will return `SPRoleCollection`. If we want to list all the roles we need to loop that.

For example an User has "Full Control","Read","Design" we need to loop the SPRoleCollection object.

How can i get all the roles as a string with ',' separator?

Answer (score 2):

As a rough guess, try:

```
var user = SPUser // However you get the user.

var roles = Sring.Join(",", (from r in user.Roles select r.Name).ToArray()));
```

Though if you're using SharePoint 2010, the `Name` property is [obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprole.name.aspx) apparently.

Comment: i am using sharepoint 2007. is there any way to do that in MOSS

Comment: SharePoint 2007 and MOSS are the same thing (pretty much), so they share the same API. Thus, the above code should work for both.